# Purpose of pegged asssets

Tags: defi, audit

I'm auditing my first smart contract for a protocol that issues pegged assets collateralized by liquid ETH staking tokens. It also has a decentralized orderbook exchange where you can buy and sell the pegged assets. And the way the pegged assets are issued is kind of unique because it is like a CDP except there are two parties - a shorter who brings most of the LST collateral, a person who wants to go long on ETH and bring the rest of the LST collateral, and the person going long gets the pegged asset and the short gets a short collateralized by all the LST.

What I'm wondering is when you are auditing a protocol, are you typically told what, say, the  pegged assets issued by the protocol are anticipated to be used for (particularly off the protocol itself)? In this protocol, people may do the shorts because they want to go long or short but why would anyone buy or sell the pegged asset if there isn't anything to use it for really (other than maybe liquidation). There is a token but you don't get it just for exchanging the asset on the platform.

But I was thinking maybe you just aren't told this during the audit process but there are usually some plans?

Comment: Ideally, everything related to the protocol should had been disclosed before the audit. In reality, lots of times the protocol hasn't been finished yet so some parts are incomplete. We can only speculate that the token will have a more defined purpose in the future, staking, voting.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not really any of your business imo, you're doing an audit, you're looking for vulnerabilities in the code base you're provided, not for purpose